# ios/xcode/coredata: Data model for many to many relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many

IOS newb from mysql background working on an app that ties into a web server backend.  If I have two entities or objects enjoying many to many relationships such as item and tag, in MYSQL I would have three tables, the table of items, the table of tags and a third table of tag-item relationships.

Table 1 Tags
ID|tag

Table 2 Items
ID|item

Table 3 Tagitems
ID|tagid|itemid

If I want to do this in core data would it be appropriate to also have three entities?

Entity 1: Tags
id|tagname

Entity 2: Items
id|itemname

Entity 3: Tagitems
id|tagid|itemid

Seems straightforward enough but just want to make sure I am understanding core data correctly.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-CJBDBHCB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intermediate table has no other attributes, then you do not need to model it yourself.  Just create a to-many relationship from `Entity 1` to `Entity 2`, and a to-many relationship from `Entity 2` to `Entity 1`, and make each relationship the inverse of the other.  CoreData will build and manage the intermediate table for you (and its existence is largely hidden from you).  The model editor should look something like this:

[image]

When you generate subclasses, CoreData will create NSSet properties for the relationships:

```
Tag.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Item;

@interface Tag : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * tagName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *items;
@end

@interface Tag (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addItemsObject:(Item *)value;
- (void)removeItemsObject:(Item *)value;
- (void)addItems:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeItems:(NSSet *)values;
@end

Item.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Tag;

@interface Item : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *tags;
@end

@interface Item (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addTagsObject:(Tag *)value;
- (void)removeTagsObject:(Tag *)value;
- (void)addTags:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeTags:(NSSet *)values;
@end
```

You can then use the core data generated accessors to add and remove relationships - note that you set the relationships directly between objects, you don't have to use IDs; CoreData is handling the IDs for you "in the shadows".  So you could do something like this:

```
Tag *actionTag = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tag" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
actionTag.name = @"Action";
Tag *dramaTag = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tag" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
dramaTag.name = @"Drama";

Item *movie = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
movie.name = @"Pride and Prejudice";
[movie addTagsObject:dramaTag];
```

If your intermediate table does have other attributes, then you should implement `Entity 3`, and add whatever attributes you need (but do not implement the 'id' keys - leave that to CoreData).  The relationships from `Entity 1` to `Entity 3` should be to-many, but its inverse should be to-one; likewise from `Entity 2` to `Entity 3` should be to-many, and its inverse to-one:

```
Entity 2 <---->> Entity 3 <<----> Entity 1
```

Comment: But only some items have some tags.  There has to be a way to let core data know which tags have which entities.  For example if the items are movies and the tags are action and drama, you have to tell the underlying dbase this movie is action and that movie is drama.  Is there a way to do this without a third table?

Comment: I'll expand my answer.

Comment: That makes sense.  Your answer seems right as I asked the question.  However, to clarify these tags are user generated not hardcoded, so there might be an unlimited number of combinations.  In that case, am I okay using a 3rd table or would I be missing out on the power of core data?

Comment: The two-entity solution should be able to cope with unlimited numbers of combinations - you can add as many tags to an item as you like (or add as many items to a tag as you like).  But using an intermediate entity will be OK, it won't significantly limit CoreData.